# Using custom emoji in bot messages // Telegram [Telebot]

Tags: python, emoji, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I have any custom emoji pack, and need to use emojies from this pack in bot messages, using Telebot(TelegramBotApi)

In fact we need an "html tag" to attach our custom emojis in a message. We didn't find these tags where ever we searched for them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your bot to be able to use custom emoji, you'll have to purchase a username for it on Telegrams platform Fragment. See the last bullet point in the release notes of Bot API 6.7: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#april-21-2023

Comment: Thx, but isn't there some other way?

Comment: no, there is not. If I knew any other solution, I would have mentioned it ;)